# Angular: unique service for sharing data between users (not components!)

Tags: angular, data-sharing, multiple-users

I've created a project in Angular that has several services that serve some components and provide several functions. I then created the official version with ng build and put my project on the server.
**Now I run into a problem.**
Each user who accesses that project on the server will have his own copy of the project on his device, so copies of the related services will also be created.
**Is there any trick to declaring a server-wide service in Angular?**
This is because, in the case of data shared by a database, it is not possible to understand the real-time modifications of the data (who is modifying something and what has modified)

I've done some research on the internet but I can't find a solution

Comment: It's absolutely normal that "each user will have his own copy of the project on his device". If you need to synchronise data between all clients, look into web sockets, server sent events, SignalR (if your backend is .net)